# correct way to add mod_wsgi module to apache

Tags: python, macos, apache

I'm trying to install the mod_wsgi module in the default apache server on mac osx. I'm following [this guy's tutorial.](http://baltazaar.wordpress.com/2011/09/09/easy-way-to-get-apache-and-mod_wsgi-working-on-os-x/) I've gotten to the part where I add the module to the apache config, and I insert these two lines:

```
$ sudo nano /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
...
LoadModule wsgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias / /Library/WebServer/Documents/
...
```

Back at the terminal I type:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart
```

When I go to visit localhost/testpy.py in my browser, I get an error saying could not connect to local host. This is my `testpy.py` file:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
status = ’200 OK’
output = ‘Hello World!’

response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
start_response(status, response_headers)

return [output]
```

### EDIT

The apache error log does not produce anything when I have those two lines of code added. When I take them out and go to a URL that I know was working before I get this in the error log:

```
caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using my-machine.local for ServerName
Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
Digest: done
Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: what happens if you just enter `http://127.0.0.1/` in your browser?

Comment: I think your tutorial is leading you astray, you might want to find a different one...

Comment: @MattDMo Perhaps it is... can you point me to a different one? `http://127.0.0.1/` produces the same problem.

Comment: I personally really like [Django](http://www.djangoproject.org). It's pretty straightforward to set up, and they have a terrific tutorial on getting everything going. Best of all, it includes its own development server, so you don't even need Apache/mod_wsgi in the beginning.

Comment: also, make sure you've followed [these instructions](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnMacOSX) on installing `mod_wsgi` on OSX

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you've followed is, unfortunately, not helpful. WSGI isn't really a method for just running Python files when you browse to them: you can already do that directly with CGI. The normal way to use WSGI is to create an application that services all URLs under a certain prefix (which may be empty), by running the wsgi file.

So, you have three issues. Firstly, your WSGIScriptAlias needs to point to an actual file, in this case your `testpy.py` file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /Library/WebServer/Documents/testpy.py
```

Secondly, that file needs to be valid Python: that is, it needs to be indented correctly, since indentation is significant in Python.

Thirdly, since the alias is pointing to `/`, that is the URL you should go to.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've added `testpy.py` to the alias, properly indented my python code, and I'm going to localhost and 127.0.0.1 in my browser and I'm still getting "could not connect".

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is a bad idea to set WSGIScriptAlias to the same directory as DocumentRoot.

The actual problem though would likely have been that you should have:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /Library/WebServer/Documents
```

That is, remove the trailing slash from directory path.

You perhaps should also read the official mod_wsgi documentation at:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide
- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines

Having the target be a directory of WSGI script files is not necessarily the most appropriate thing to do so check the documentation for other options.

Using some arbitrary persons blog post is nearly never a good substitute for the official documentation.